# Are Neural Networks only really useful for Image Classification?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, classification

Let's say I wanted to predict whether someone was Male or Female based on what they answered to certain survey questions.

I can see something like a Random Forest or KNN being useful here, but is there any reasons you'd apply a Neural Network? Or would it just be overkill?

Answer (score 3):

Random forest would probably do fine enough. KNN maybe not as well if survey questions have discrete data - continuous data may also be fine, but i don't imagine it will be as robust as random forests. With a lot of data, neural networks would do very well though. Only concern with using neural nets would be overparameterizing and not having enough data.

I would argue that it's not really an overkill if you have enough data and don't over parameterize. Generally, you don't know which model you build is more generalizable unless you try and see how it does on held out test sets. Neural nets can definitely applied in more fields than just computer vision.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. I guess I'm just seeing most applications of Neural Nets revolving around image classification (but I'm maybe just looking in the wrong place). Do you mind elaborating on why KNN wouldn't be as robust?

Comment: A distance in discrete data is not well defined usually (ofc you can define it, but it may not make sense for 0/1 variables). I don't think KNN would be as good for continuous data but that would depend on your data. If doing image class, imgs of dogs to other dogs may look similar (there is still large variation still to make this questionable based on distance measure - maybe color plays too much of a role) vs dogs to cats. If survey questions, to me there would be more trouble interpreting distances of questions meaningfully so KNN may not do as well

Comment: a combination of discrete and continuous variables would further complicate because of distances to resolve the different data types and meanings of distances. Maybe you interpret a discrete variable as continuous , but it may not lend itself to an ordinal scale